# from clause issue with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
mysql> describe events;
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| city_id         | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
```

Following sql is causing error.

```
  SELECT CONCAT_WS('',users.fname,' ', users.lname) as user_name,
   COUNT(events.id) AS events_count
  FROM users
   INNER JOIN events ON users.id = events.user_id
   INNER JOIN cities ON cities.id = events.city_id
  GROUP BY
    users.id
  WHERE
    events.city_id = 18
  ORDER BY
   COUNT(events.id) DESC
  LIMIT 10
```

Error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE
        events.city_id = 18
```

If I remove the WHERE clause then everything works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting the `WHERE` clause before the `GROUP BY`

Comment: Yes. That solved the problem. I never knew that it was a requirement to have where clause before "group by". Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

use WHERE before GROUP BY and it should work

Answer (score 2):

`WHERE` needs to come before `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 1):

Put the `events.city_id=18` condition in the JOIN. There's really no reason to have it in the WHERE clause since you're doing an INNER join.

```
INNER JOIN events ON users.id = events.user_id AND events.city_id=18
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to use `GROUP BY...HAVING`?